# MAMP-PHP not working with SASS

Tags: php, sass

I would like to use sass using MAMP and PHP.

I have put the correct path which is 
`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hello/` and then i have insert `sass --watch css/app.scss:css/custom.css` which is also the correct path and I have the correct msg which is `>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.`

However, when I make the changes nothing happens.

Any ideas what the problem is?

I have used everything as I would have made in my html projects but for some reason this is not working.

Comment: What are the permissions of the file (`custom.css`)?